# Distribution ratio of $\bar{y}$ and $S_x$ when $X$ and $Y$ are correlated normally distributed

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

If we have two correlated $X\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$ with correlation $\rho$, then $\bar{y}$ has $N(\mu_1,\frac{\sigma^2_1}n)$ and $S_x$ follows $f(s_x)=\frac{2\left(\frac{n}{2\sigma^2_2}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)} e^{-\frac{nS^2}{2\sigma^2}}s_x^{n-2}$ (reference [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html)) and $n$ is fixed.
Now my question is what should be the distribution of $\frac{\bar{y}}{S_x}$.